# Jenkins dynamically put checkbox

Tags: checkbox, jenkins

Let's say I have a dropdown list parameter with a few selections and I want one of the selections to bring checkboxes, otherwise they will not be shown.

How can I do that? I tried Extended Parameter but no help, please help me.

First selection will call another multi-choice selections (checkboxes),

But only one selection will do that, others will not bring another selection.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Ross Tracy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374864/1744774):

- Add an ***Active Choices Parameter*** with:

  *Name*: `Active_Choices_Parameter`

  *Groovy Script*:

  ```
  return [
    '',
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third'
  ]
  ```

  *Choice Type*: `Single Select`
- Add an ***Active Choices Reactive Parameter*** with:

  *Name*: `Active_Choices_Reactive_Parameter`

  *Groovy Script*:

  ```
  if ( Active_Choices_Parameter.equals('') )
    return ''
  else if ( Active_Choices_Parameter.equals('First') )
    return [
      '1. Fourth',
      '1. Fifth',
      '1. Sixth'
    ]
  ```

  *Choice Type*: `Check Boxes`

  *Referenced parameters*: `Active_Choices_Parameter`

Comment: Where and how to put all those groovy script ? Should I put them all together ?

Comment: @RasimAVCI In a project's config → _General_ → [x] _This build is parameterized_. Are you not familiar with Jenkins and how to configure a project in it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin), although with a slightly different need.  I have an initial drop down, that when chosen, populates the next parameter, which is another drop down with data specific to the first choice.

It's pretty versatile and there are many options in the documentation.  Depending on the depth of your need, this may work for you.

Comment: Instead of this I used Extended Choice Parameter with Multi-Level Multi-Select option but when sending its values I am confused. It takes parameters from a properties file then in the command areas section I wrote to sent my test tool this /testvar:CustomSuite='%CustomSuite%'   Then I added 3 imtes and Build my job However in the console output I see that it only sent one value, the second one choose -in the middle- What is logi here how can I send my values ??

Comment: @RasimAVCI Did you see my second answer after I deleted the first which referred to _Extended Choice Parameter_ and which you commented with "_this is not answer to my exact question. I know and use Extended Choice already, it only brings another dropdownlist for every selection. What I want is dynamically show checkboxes on screen when a selection done, not another dropdown list._"?

Comment: Yeah I saw and I wrote another comment to that answer already and that solution seemed a little bit confusing and real problem is we dont have that plugin in our jenkins. I think I can use Extended Choice with Multi-Level Multi-Select option.Can you tell me how can I use each value that I added with "Select Another" button ?

Comment: @RasimAVCI I saw your last reply just by chance. Therefore a hint: If you don't address a comment to someone with _@<username>_ in a question or answer of somebody else, he/she will not be notified about it. See also [Replying in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @GeroldBroser Thanks Gerold

Answer (score 0):

See ***Extended Choice Parameter*** → *Multi-level Parameter Types* → *Parameter Type: Multi-Level Multi Select* of the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin). From its inline help:

> - Multi-Level Single Select: ...
>
>   The property file is a tab delimited file, with levels defined in columns and choices defined in rows. For example, to have a 2 level selection where you first select a country and then a city, you could specify a file such as the following:
>     
>      `Country⇥City
>     United States⇥San Francisco
>     United States⇥Chicago
>     Mexico⇥Mexico City
>     Mexico⇥Cancun`
>     This would result in a first drop down with the options "Select a country...", "United States", and "Mexico" (the initial selection is "Select a country...", which serves as a label for the drop down). After the user selects a country, a "City" drop down would appear. If United States was chosen first, then San Francisco and Chicago would be options, but if Mexico was selected then instead Mexico City and Cancun would be options.
>     
>     The columns that should represent levels must be specified in the value field. For example "Country,City" could be valid values.
>     
>     Note that default values are not supported for multi-level selects.
> - Multi-Level Multi Select: same as single select, but after all levels are chosen, a button appears to "Select another..." and an additional multi-level selection is presented.

- So, add an ***Extended Choice Parameter*** with:

  *Name*: `Extended_Choice_Parameter`

  ◉ *Multi-level Parameter Types*

  *Property File*: `<absolut path to file>/Multi-level_parameters.txt`

  *Parameter Type*: `Multi-Level Single Select` or `Multi-Level Multi Select`

  *Value*: `Country,City`

Comment: Ross this is not answer to my exact question. I know and use  Extended Choice already, it only brings another dropdownlist for every selection. What I want is dynamically show checkboxes on screen when a selection done, not another dropdown list.

Comment: @RasimAVCI I'm not Ross.